# Since when did Chrome disable support for WebGL when hardware acceleration is off?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

Recently I noticed that my chrome cannot use WebGL when hardware acceleration is disabled. I don't think this is true in previous versions of Chrome (not sure which exact version they disabled this, though). Right now if I turn hardware acceleration off, I can't get the webgl context from a canvas element. Any information on why the chrome team did this?

Besides, I have no idea why when I turned off hardware acceleration on chrome in previous versions, I can still get the webgl context. Isn't WebGL depends completely on GPU? So how does previous version of chrome support WebGL without GPU? Thanks!